# implementing nested fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction, android-nested-fragment

I have a GenericContainer That extends an activity.

GenericContainer takes case of my fragments, i am using viewStubs to populate them.

How to implement nested fragments in GenericContainer. I will be opening stubOne first and then from stubOne I will be navigating to stubTwo. On clicking on back on stubTwo I 
should be coming back to stubOne.

GenericContainer

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.layout_form_container);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        if(FormContainer.class.isAssignableFrom(getClass())) {
            mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_close_white_24px);
        }

        if(null != mStubForm.getParent()) {
            int layoutId = getIntent().getExtras().getInt(AppConstants.KEY_STUB_LAYOUT_ID);
            mStubForm.setLayoutResource(layoutId);
            mStubForm.inflate();
        }
    }
```

I will open the STUB one and stubOno using the code below.

```
public void openStubOne(String title) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), GenericContainer.class);

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelable(KEY_SEARCH_OPTIONS, accountSearchEntity);
        bundle.putInt(AppConstants.KEY_STUB_LAYOUT_ID, R.layout.layout_stub_ONE);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);

        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
        startActivityForResult(intent, AppConstants.REQUEST_CODE_FORM_CONTAINER);

}
```

stubTwo

public void openStubTwo(String title) {

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), GenericContainer.class);

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(AppConstants.KEY_SCREEN_TITLE, title);
    bundle.putInt(AppConstants.KEY_STUB_LAYOUT_ID, R.layout.layout_stub_two);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);

    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
    startActivityForResult(intent, AppConstants.REQUEST_CODE_FORM_CONTAINER);
```

}

Your help is much appreciated

Comment: In general nested fragments and transactions should be avoided-  they've never worked really well (nesting them without transactions is ok).

Comment: can you let me know how to do that please.